# Are there null like thing in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, contract

```
struct buyer {
    uint amount;
    Status status;
}

mapping(address=>buyer) public buyers;
mapping(uint=>address) buyerIndex;
uint public buyerNum;

// Order a product.
function() {
    uint doubleValue=value*2;
    uint amount=msg.value/doubleValue;
    if(buyers[msg.sender]==null) { // Error in this line
        buyer abuyer=buyer({amount:amount,status:Status.Created}); // Error in this line
        buyerNum++;
        buyerIndex[buyerNum]=msg.sender;
        buyers[msg.sender]=abuyer;
    }
    else {
        buyers[msg.sender].amount+=amount;
    }
    Order(msg.sender,amount*doubleValue,amount);
}
```

If a buyer is not recorded in the buyer mapping, then buyerNum++;
but I don't know how to tell whether a buyer is in the mapping

Comment: Maybe like [How can I check if a variable or an array is set or empty or null](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2134/87), [Checking zero value of structure](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2502/87) or [What is the zero value for a string](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5683/87) at Ethereum Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 22):

In solidity every variable is set to `0` by default.

You should think of `mappings` **as all possible** combinations are set to `0` by default.

In your specific case I would use the following:

```
if (buyers[msg.sender].amount == 0)
```

Comment: You can also just say: `if (buyers[msg.sender].amount) { ... }`

Answer (score 13):

### For integers:

You could create `none` variable to use it as a `NULL`:

```
uint256 constant NULL = 0;
```

Example code for check:

```
function isNULL(uint256 variable) internal returns (bool) {
    return variable == NULL;
}
```

---

### For `bytes32`:

You can follow different approach for `bytes`:

```
bytes32 constant NULL = "";
```

Example code piece:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

mapping(address => bytes32) public Countries;   

function isCountriesInitialized(address _user) external view returns (bool) 
{
    if (Countries[_user] == NULL) // Returns true if `Countries[_user]` is not initialized
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

---

I observe that on solidity >= `v0.6.0` it may return 32 for length even though it is not mapped.

Example of its returned value:

`b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Answer (score 5):

As Viktor said, default value for all possible values in mapping is zero. So if a `buyer` has not already inserted in mapping, the `amount` value for that `address` will be zero. But this approach has a flaw, if a `buyer` does exists but its balance became zero after some operations, you will treat it as it does not exist.

I think the best approach is to add a `exists` member to the `buyer` struct with `bool` type. Default value for this member is `false` and when the buyer get created, you initialize it with `true` value. So you can check exactly if a buyer exist or not via this member.

Buyer struct:

```
struct buyer{
   uint amount;
   Status status;
   bool exists;
}
```

Initialize buyer:

```
buyer memory b = buyer(0, status, true);
```

Check if buyer exists:

```
if(buyers[msg.sender].exists) {
  //so can buy
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing like `null` in solidity.

Just check for the length of the address:

```
if(buyers[msg.sender].length == 0){
    // do your thing
}
```

See also [this answer on ethereum stack exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2504/87).

Comment: Structs does not have `length` member.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using one of the values or creating an extra `boolean`, you can check for the `byte` size of the `structure`.

```
if (bytes(buyers[msg.sender]).length > 0) {
    // buyer exists.
}
```