# What is the initial value of Ethereum contract variables?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I make some contracts code with mapping data. When I first access data value, ethereum returns `0`.

Is it specification of ethereum? In other word, Can I write a contract on the assumption that variable's initial value is `0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there null like thing in solidity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37852682/1260906). See also [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2134/87),  [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2502/87) and [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5683/87) over at [Ethereum Stack Exchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is the default behavior. Each types have a "zero-state" default value.
For example boolean have a default value of *false*, integer a default value of *0* and strings a default value of *""*

You can read more here http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#default-value